# paging (horizontal swiping) through multiple uitableviews

Tags: uiscrollview, paging, uitableview

I am trying to put a number tables in uiscrollview such that it can swipe through each (paging). This is done on nicely on TweetDeck.

I'm using https://github.com/andreyvit/SoloComponents-iOS/tree/master/ATPagingView

However im struggling to figure out how to do it without leaking memory.

```
- (UIView *)viewForPageInPagingView:(ATPagingView *)pagingView atIndex:(NSInteger)index {

   myTableViewController *t = [[servicesController alloc] init]; 
   t.delegate = self.navigationController; //such that the tableview can call nav controller
   t.info = [array objectAtIndex:index]; //Data that is different for every page
   return [t.view autorelease];

}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I should modify  ATPagingView to accomodate for UIViewControllers instead of UIViews? Or any other examples?